# Output all entries in Gloss, no text being produced

Tags: bibtex, glossaries, gloss

I'm trying to use `gloss` to output a entries from a `.bib` file like a dictionary in alphabetical order. For some reason I can't get it to output anything except the title. I'm using TexWorks in windows.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} %use 1'' margins instead of default latex margins
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indents first paragraph
\usepackage[refpages]{gloss}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{style.bib}
@gd{test,
word = {test},
definition = {test entry}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makegloss

\begin{document}
\emph{The Rensselaer Polytechnic} Style Guide
\gloss[nocite]{*}
\printgloss{style}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\makegloss`, supposing your `.tex` file is named `myfile.tex`, generates a file `myfile.gls.aux` which has to be processes by BibTeX to produce the correct entries in the glossary.

So, as the `gloss` package documentation states, you have to run, in the order,

> latex myfile
>
> bibtex myfile.gls
>
> latex myfile
>
> latex myfile

to get the correct output.

If you follow the above steps, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Hi, this was what I thought I was doing in TeXworks using pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX, but it turns out that BibTeX was searching for a myfile.aux instead of the myfile.gls.aux so I changed the arguments in the processor for it and that fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @EthanSpitz: For cases like this you should create an own compile command instead of changing the original arguments.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did, just didn't phrase it so clearly :)